# Check if Service is Running or Stopped and Output accordingly

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-5.0

I'm just starting off with Powershell and want to run some basic scripts.

I'm starting off by writing a script to see if MSSQLSERVER is running or stopped and out a message accordingly.

This is what I have so far...

```
Write-Host "Checking if SQL Server is running.."

function FuncCheckService{
param($MSSQLSERVER)
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $MSSQLSERVER
if ($arrService.Status -eq "Running"){
Write-Host "Service is running" 
}
if ($arrService.Status -eq "Stopped"){ 
Write-Host "service is stopped"
}
}
```

However when I execute this (within Powershell ISE) all I get is the first line "Checking if SQL Server is running..."

What am I doing wrong with this?

Comment: You defined a function, but didn't call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is fine but you never call it. at the end of the scripts, just past the last curly braces put your function name.

Comment: Great thanks. However... I'm getting this error now.."$.Status : The term '$.Status' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo? I cut/pasted your code above and executed it without error.